# How to handle System.InvalidCastException while fetching data from a web url. (in C# WinForm)

Tags: c#, json, winforms

1. I made a program in which I am fetching payment status from a url and then parsing the response using json.
2. In WinForm Application I have payment button by clicking on which I receive data from url but if the token or data passed is wrong then my application is unable to handle exception and not printing custom error on console its giving System.InvalidCastException only .
3. Here is my C# program

```cs
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public static class RestHelper
    {
        static string tokenKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(
            @"C:\Users\Asus\source\repos\WinFormsApp1\Tokken.txt"
        );

        static string userId = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(
            @"C:\Users\Asus\source\repos\WinFormsApp1\UserId.txt"
        );

        private static readonly string baseURL =
            "https://paymentddn.gov.in:8085/getChallanByNo/" + tokenKey + "/";

        private static readonly string baseURL3 = "/" + userId;

        private static readonly string baseURL1 = "https://paymentddn.gov.in:8085/dverify/";

        public static async Task<string> GetAll(string challanNo)
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (
                        HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(
                            baseURL + challanNo + baseURL3
                        )
                    )
                    {
                        using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
                        {
                            string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            if (data != null)
                            {
                                return data;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Server Error " + e.Message);
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        public static string BeautifyJson(string jsonStr)
        {
            // JToken parseJson = JToken.Parse(jsonStr);
            //return parseJson.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
            string[] m = jsonStr.Split("|");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("Payment Status = " + m[2]);
            sb.Append("\n");
            sb.Append("Challan No = " + m[5]);
            sb.Append("\n");
            sb.Append("Invoice = " + m[6]);
            sb.Append("\n");
            sb.Append("Amount = " + m[7]);
            sb.Append("\n");
            sb.Append("Status = " + m[8]);
            sb.Append("\n");
            sb.Append("Payment Mode = " + m[12]);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static async Task<string> Get(string rcpNo)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(baseURL1 + rcpNo))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
                    {
                        string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            return data;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

4. The Above Class is named as RestHelper in which I am fetching data and doing parsing for the response

   > namespace WinFormsApp1
   > {
   > public partial class Form1 : Form
   > {
   > public Form1()
   > {
   > InitializeComponent();
   > }
   >
   > ```
   >             private async void btnGetAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   >             {
   >                 try
   >                 {
   >                     var responce = await RestHelper.GetAll(txtChallan.Text);
   >     
   >                     JObject mRespose = JObject.Parse(responce.ToString());
   >                     JObject mParent = (JObject)mRespose["myObjectList"];
   >                     JObject mPaymentModel = (JObject)mParent["paymentInfoModel"];
   >                     string rcpNo = (string)mPaymentModel["receiptNo"];
   >     
   >                     Console.WriteLine("Response pay ==  " + rcpNo);
   >     
   >                     var responce1 = await RestHelper.Get(rcpNo);
   >                     txtResponce.Text = RestHelper.BeautifyJson(responce1.ToString());
   >                     // txtResponce.Text = RestHelper.BeautifyJson(responce);
   >                 }catch(System.Exception d)
   >                 {
   >                     Console.WriteLine("Server Error"+ d.Message);
   >                 }
   >     
   >     
   >             }
   >     
   >             private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   >             {
   >     
   >             }
   >     
   >             private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   >             {
   >     
   >             }
   >     
   >             private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   >             {
   >     
   >             }
   >         }
   >     }
   > ```
5. This is Form1.cs class in which I am calling GetAll And Get method from RestHelper.
6. I used try catch block and tried to change my `Task<string>` to `Task<Object>` but still getiing same exception.

> 'WinFormsApp1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.17\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll'.
>
> ```
> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in WinFormsApp1.dll
> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in WinFormsApp1.dll
> 'WinFormsApp1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.17\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll'.
>
> The program '[29328] WinFormsApp1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> ```

Comment: Just a guess, but `JObject mParent = (JObject)mRespose["myObjectList"];` should probably be a `JArray`? But anyway: Why not create a decent model to deserialize to in the first place?

Comment: Actually I am getting payment status one at a time so I used json object

Comment: in myObjectList I am getting response from url and then I am Parsing it in custom way as you can see in BeautiFyJson method

Comment: Why do you think you need "a custom way"? There is a reason, why people deserialize json to models and work on those.

Comment: yes but here is the issue with the casting and yes json to model is better

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is pretty easy instead of using `Console.Writeline` use `MessageBox.Show((string)mRespose["message"], "Server Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);`.

In Form1.cs class put MessageBox in catch part and use custom message in it .